# Can't see the back button in Navigation View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

For some reason I can't see the back button in the Navigation View.

I don't know if there is some extra code that I need to add in the child view but I don't know. I more or less copied the code from the tutorial, but I can't see the back button in the child view.

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //Rectangle 12
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7137255072593689, green: 0.10196077823638916, blue: 0.10196077823638916, alpha: 1)))
                .frame(width: .infinity, height: 50)
                .padding(.bottom, 0.0)
            
            
            NavigationView {
                ZStack{
                    Color(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    
                    
                    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                        
                        HStack{
                            Text("Marketplace").font(.custom("Arial", size: 35))
                                .fontWeight(.medium)
                                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1))
                                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 15, leading: 20, bottom: -2, trailing: 0))

                            Spacer()
                        }
                
                        ForEach(produitsdfsdf, id: \.id ) { product in
                            
                            NavigationLink(destination: TempView()) {
                                LandingPresets.listItem(name: product.name, description: product.price, rate: product.category)
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                    
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, -8.0)
            
            
        }.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
            .onAppear {
                ProductAPI().getAllProducts {(productArr) in
                    self.produitsdfsdf = productArr
                }
            }
        
        
    }
```

Comment: The navigation view should be at the highest point of the app and more important don’t hide the navigation bar, that is where the button is located.

Comment: The navigation view must be in the header, it is a parent view.

Comment: Please put in your code for `TempView`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of you use `.navigationBarHidden(true)` in main View.
You could add `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)` to your TempView().
If you give code of TempView, I'll be able to show to which part of code.